# Minimal planar domain

Tags: definition

I am recently studing minimal surfaces on my own. I have meet in many places the fallowing statement:

The only connected, properly embedded, minimal planar domains in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are a plane, a helicoid, a catenoid or one of the Riemann minimal examples.

for example in [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.1690). But without definition of **planar domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$**, may someone familiar with the topic give the definition or reference to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 3 of the pdf you linked to:

> [image]

Comment: Many thanks even thought i used "find" function i missed that :P, for surness embeding into plane is equivalent to having global parametrization with domain being full $\mathbb{R}^2$, right?